# Run JS within shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, d3.js, shiny

I am having troubles understanding how the logic of calling `JavaScript` in `Shiny` for `R` works.

I have a `.js` file called `first.js`.
In there I have something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    firstFunc = function() {

....
}
});
```

I include it in `ui.R` like so:

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="first.js"))
```

I then call the function `firstFunc` like this:

```
tags$body(onload="firstFunc()")
```

That works!
When I try to include a `second.js` in another way, I am having troubles.
Lets say I want to do something with `d3`. I include the `d3` library in `ui.R`

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="d3.min.js"))
```

I then write something very trivial into `second.js`

```
d3.select(".whateverClass").append("text").text("test");
```

When I include my `second.js` file, which only contains the `d3.select...` like this (without calling a function `secondFunc()` like in the first example)

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="second.js"))
```

Its not working. **BUT**, when I write `d3.select...` into my `first.js`, within the brackets of `firstFunc()` it works.

Why do I have to call a function (here `firstFunc()`) in order to execute the the Code? Why can't I simply link to the `.js` file?

Comment: I assume you `second.js` also has the `document.ready` part?

Comment: @warmoverflow nope, it does not

Comment: You need something to trigger your JavaScript code (`onload`, `ready` etc) otherwise it's not going to run.